# Python JSON generate new nested element

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": 1400162618,
        "style": "",
        "category": "sdf",
        "popup": "sd"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to add to the "style" several new sub-elements with values. The new JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": 1400162618,
        "style": {
             "radius": 8,
             "color": "#428ed2"
      },
        "category": "sdf",
        "popup": "sd"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to to that with

```
import json

geoJson = json.load(open('sample.geojson'))

features = geoJson["features"]
for feat in features:
  feat["properties"]["style"]["radius"] = 2
```

But I get: KeyError: 'style'

How can I assign new elements to a JSON?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. Once you've called `json.load` on the content, it's now a perfectly normal Python dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to first initialize it to a dict

```
for feat in features:
  feat["properties"]["style"] = {}  #initializing to dict
  feat["properties"]["style"]["radius"] = 2
  feat["properties"]["style"]["color"] = "#428ed2"
```

or directly assign a dict

```
for feat in features:
  feat["properties"]["style"] = {"radius": 2, "color": "#428ed2"}
```